# Inequality about sequences satisfied $S_n\le \lambda n$

Tags: sequences-and-series, algebra-precalculus, inequality

> A nonnegative sequence $\{a_n\}$ satisfies that at least $n$ of the first $n^2$ terms of the sequence $\{a_n\}$ are greater than $n$, and the sum of the first $n$ terms $S_n\le \lambda n$ holds for any positive integer $n$.
>
> Find the minimum of $\lambda\in\mathbb R$.

I managed to construct an example that shows $\lambda=2$ is right:

$$ 1 , 0+\epsilon,2,3,0+\epsilon,0+\epsilon,0+\epsilon,4,5, 0+\epsilon,0+\epsilon,0+\epsilon,0+\epsilon,0+\epsilon,6,7, ... $$

where $\epsilon$ is a sufficiently small positive number.

but I can't prove that is exactly the smallest case.

Comment: Why all the leading zeroes in the terms of the your sequence?

Comment: @Opisthokont: What 73dsi probably means is the sequence $1, 0, 2, 3, 0, 0, 0, 4, 5, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 6, 7,\ldots$.

Comment: Does "greater than $n$" here mean "greater than or equal to $n$"?

Comment: @Opisthokont No. In fact, the 0 in my example should be replaced by 0 + ε, where ε is a sufficiently small positive number